# Python Image object to WxPython

Tags: python, wxpython, python-imaging-library

I just want to display python image object in wxpython panel.

What i am trying to accomplish is taking screenshot using python ImageGrab or autopy and showing it in wxpython panel. My screenshot program running every second so there is no point save the image for wx.

> ```
> import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
> imgobj = ImageGrab.grab()
> print imgobj
> # Convert into wximage
> myWxImage = wx.EmptyImage( imgobj.size[0], imgobj.size[0] )
> myWxImage.SetData( imgobj.convert( 'RGB' ).tostring())
> ```

Output

> ```
> <Image.Image image mode=RGB size=1366x768 at 0x20B98F0> 
> ValueError:Invalid data buffer size.
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your problem is that you are passing the image width as new height to wx...

And btw instead you could use

`myWxImage = wx.ImageFromBuffer( imgobj.size[0], imgobj.size[1], imgobj.tostring() )`

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy to tell without a full traceback, but I think the issue might be this typo:

```
myWxImage = wx.EmptyImage( imgobj.size[0], imgobj.size[0] )
```

Should be:

```
myWxImage = wx.EmptyImage( imgobj.size[0], imgobj.size[1] )
```

Also you could make your code simpler with:

```
myWxImage = wx.ImageFromBuffer(imgobj.size[0], imgobj.size[1], imgobj.convert('RGB').tostring())
```